# Does hsqldb support table alias in oracle compatible mode

Tags: oracle, alias, hsqldb

We're using hsqdb-2.2.9 in dao tests. The hsqldb was made compatible with oracle (in production) by setting `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;` and we use ibatis sql map.

It gets failed when the sql contains table alias, something like `select a.name, b.code form t_a a, t_b b where a.id = b.a_id` , which reports `unexpected token a`. We tried adding 'as' between table and table alias, it doesn't work either. Do I miss something?

Comment: `form` should be `from`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HSQLDB supports table aliases.

If you use the exact query you reported, you would get:

```
 unexpected token: T_A
```

If you correct the query as commented by a_horse_with_no_name it should work. If one of the tables does not exist, you would get:

```
  user lacks privilege or object not found: T_A
```

BTW, try using the latest 2.3.0 snapshot jar for better Oracle compatibility tests. You can find it from the support page of the website.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i corrects the sql and get' user lacks privilege or object not found: ' but the table does exist actaully， is there any other possiblities? @fredt

Answer (score 0):

uh.... I think I‘ve found the issue........of my own.  It suddenly occur to me that I use ’do‘ (table name is t_delivery_order) as the table alias which happens to be a keyword in hsqldb(or in sql). Just replace 'do’ with 'd', its fixed. Thank u all